# How to import a .csv file to existing table on sql server on Azure Data Studio?

Tags: .net, sql-server, csv, azure-data-studio

I am using mac m1 so I can't use SSMS, I can use Azure Data Studio. I want to import an excel file to my existing table on SQL Server. If I use BULK INSERT sql query, it gives an error because Azure Data Studio cannot see local file storage except Azure Blob Storage. If I use SQL Server Import extension, it gives an error like table already exists. How to I solve that? I must write .NET application with using .csv data.

Comment: *"because Azure Data Studio cannot see local file storage except Azure Blob Storage"* Azure Data Studio is just an IDE-like application. If you are talking about an Azure blob Storage this sounds like you are actually using an Azure SQL Database *not* SQL Server.

Comment: ADS is just a client application. `BULK INSERT` works just fine *if you use the correct path*. The path doesn't have to be local, it can be a shared folder. If you want to import a file from your dev machine to a remote server you can use the `bcp` command-line tool. You can also write code in many languages to insert the data. Eg in C# you can use SqlBulkCopy to effectively execute a `BULK INSERT` with any data. You can also use

Comment: Using `bcp` is explained in [Bulk copy data with bcp to SQL Server on Linux](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-bcp?view=sql-server-ver16). Installing `bcp` is described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver16)

Answer (score 0):

Azure Data Studio is a client application just like SSMS. Both are IDEs which means both are *unsuitable* for scripted imports and exports.

**Importing with bcp**

You can install the [SQL Server command line tools](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-setup-tools?view=sql-server-ver16#macos) on Linux or Mac and use the [bcp](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-bcp?view=sql-server-ver16) tool to import or export data from the command line or a script. The tools can be installed using Homebrew:

```
brew tap microsoft/mssql-release https://github.com/Microsoft/homebrew-mssql-release
brew update
brew install mssql-tools
```

The section [Import data from the source data file](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/linux/sql-server-linux-migrate-bcp?view=sql-server-ver16#import-data-from-the-source-data-file) shows how to import data and explains the options. The full syntax is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-ver16) :

```
bcp TestEmployees in ~/test_data.txt -S localhost -U sa -P <your_password> -d BcpSampleDB -c -t  ','
```

**Importing in .NET**

If you have to write a .NET application, you can use the [SqlBulkCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) class to import data directly into the database. The data has to be accessible through an IDataReader interface.

One way to read CSV data through an IDataReader is to use the [CsvDataReader](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/examples/csvdatareader/) class from the CsvHelper package:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(pathToCSV))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    using (var dr = new CsvDataReader(csv))
    {       
        using (var connection=new SqlConnection(connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            using (var bcp=new SqlBulkCopy(connection))
            {
                bcp.DestinationTableName = "dbo.BulkCopyDemoMatchingColumns";

                bcp.WriteToServer(reader);
            }
        }
}
```

This will work if the file headers and table columns match by position. If not, the mapping from source to target columns must be specified through the [ColumnMappings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlbulkcopy.columnmappings?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) property

Answer (score -1):

```
import sqlalchemy
import pyodbc
SERVERNAME="your server name"
DB="your database name"
engine_mssql = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f"mssql+pyodbc://{SERVERNAME}/{DB}driver=ODBC+Driver+17+for+SQL+Server",fast_executemany=True)
df=pd.read_csv("your csv file")
df.to_sql('table name',engine_mssql,if_exists='replace',index=False)
print("success")




     

`
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).